# Example of a non-trivial function such that $f(2x)=f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, contest-math, functional-equations, rational-numbers

Could you give an example of a non-constant function $f$ such that 
$$
f(x) = f(2x).
$$ 
The one that I can think of is the trivial one, namely $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$, the characteristic function on the rationals.

I am wondering if there is any other such function other than this one. TQVM!

Comment: Constant functions?

Comment: Just by curiosity, what is TQVM standing for ? I never saw this acronym anywhere.

Comment: My guess: Thank Q Very Much - taking Q to mean You

Comment: @KimJongUn I forgot to impose the restriction to non-constant functions. Thanks.

Comment: @ OP: see my answer below.

Comment: Derivation is also an example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One more example
$$f(x) = \sin(2\pi\log_2x)$$
$$f(2x) = \sin(2\pi\log_2(2x)) = \sin(2\pi(1 + \log_2x)) = \sin(2\pi\log_2x) = f(x)$$

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following function:
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{if} & x= 2^mk,\,\,\, \text{for some}\,\,\,k,m\in \mathbb Z, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Indeed, $\,\,f(2x)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

The only continuous function satisfying the relation is the constant function. Indeed the given equality gives

$$f(x)=f\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}f(0)$$

To construct a general function let $S\subset \Bbb R$ and consider the set

$$A=\{2^n s\;|\; n\in\Bbb Z,\;s\in S\}$$
and define  $f$ by
$$f(x)=\text{constant if}\; x\in A,\; \text{other constant}\;\text{otherwise} $$

Answer (score 1):

A less trivial example: define $f(0)$ to be any thing and for $x\neq 0$, define $f(x)=g(x/|x|)$ for any function $g:\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$.